# pygtk: Changing style of <a href>-label

Tags: pygtk

gtk.Label(....) gives a label as a clickable link if the label-text is formatted as a link (text within a "a href-tag"). It is then automatically shown in blue and underlined. (How) can I change the style, e.g. remove the underlining and change the color?

Python 2.7.4, Windows7, gtk 2.24.10.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a span tag to set text attribute.

Suppose label's text is:

```
<a href="http://www.gnu.org/">GNU</a>
```

now change it to:

```
<a href="http://www.gnu.org/"><span foreground="blue" underline="none">GNU</span></a>
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]